# SQL - In Select Query if I use "Not IN" then it returns result set in random order

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have used NOT IN clause in Select Statement. When I run that query, each time it returns the  same result set but the order is different.

Is this the default behavior of "NOT IN" clause?

The query which I am using is as below:

```
SELECT *,(ISNULL(AppFirstName,'')+' '+ISNULL(AppMiddleName,'')+' '+ISNULL(AppLastName,'')) as AppName FROM BApp AF WHERE AF.SId=11 AND AF.SCId=5 AND AF.CCId= 1 AND AF.IsActive=1 AND AF.ASId=16 AND AF.AId NOT IN (SELECT AId FROM NumberDetails where AId = AF.AId)
```

Comment: Which database system is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't specify an ORDER BY clause, then *no* query has a defined order. The database is free to return you the rows in whatever order is easiest for it.

The reason this sometimes seems consistent is that the rows will often be read out either in the order they exist on disk (probably the order they were inserted) or in the order of some index that was used to find the result.

The more complex your query, the more complex the processing the database needs to do, so the less likely the results are to come out in some obvious, repeatable, order.

Moral of the story: **always use an ORDER BY clause**.

Answer (score 3):

The order of an SQL result is not defined and left for the database to pick unless you use an ORDER clause. If you need to know more, post the query and what DB you are using.

Answer (score 1):

SQL, by default, does not order or sort the records it returns. This behavior isn't specific to 'NOT IN', but is a general premise of the language. However, you can easily order your results by adding an 'ORDER BY table.column_name' to the end of your query.